# RN: Class static side 'typeof *' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof BaseModel

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-native-sqlite-storage, expo-sqlite

In react native, I'm extending an ORM class (according to its documentation) but I'm getting following error in VSCode TypeScript checker:

```
Class static side 'typeof Animal' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof BaseModel'.
  Types of property 'database' are incompatible.
    Type '() => Promise<SQLite.WebSQLDatabase>' is not assignable to type 'void'.ts(2417)
```

In the end it actually works, but I would like to know if there's a way how to define it more properly or more loose so such checker error is not generated.

The ORM module is just JS (not TypeScript) **EDIT: and it's 3rd party, so I can't really edit it**

This is the parent class method in `BaseModel`:

```
  static get database() {
    throw new Error('DB not defined')
  }
```

This is the extending method of `Animal` model:

```
  static get database() {
    return async () => SQLite.openDatabase('database.db')
  }
```

Comment: How do you _use_ this property? If this is plain JS, where do types come from? What ORM is it? If it's on npm, does it also have a `@types/my-orm-here` package?

Comment: @AlexWayne My sources are in typescript files, that's where the type checking comes from I guess, and it didn't install `@types/expo-sqlite-orm` the ORM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-sqlite-orm . `database` - I don't use it, it's used internally when I use e.g. createTable on the Animal model. strange... BTW: **the error is no longer there O.o** not sure what changed, *maybe TS checker update in vscode...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript infers `BaseModel`'s `database` getter to be of type `void`. This is because you neither return a value, nor do you have an explicit type on that getter. Then `Animal` tries to extend that, and it returns an async function, which is not void, and you get the type error.

The correct fix here is to properly type the `BaseModel.database` return value. In this case, I believe it should return an async function, which returns a promise, which wraps your database object.

```
class BaseModel {
  static get database(): () => Promise<MyDb> {
    throw new Error('DB not defined')
  }
}
```

Now `Animal` works without type errors:

```
class Animal extends BaseModel {
  static get database() {
    return async () => SQLite.openDatabase('database.db')
  }
}
```

And you can get a db reference:

```
const db = await Animal.database()
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=17&ssc=3&pln=17&pc=64#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAiAjKBeKBvKATRAuKwATgK7QC+AsAFBYQDGANgIaHR0D2AdgM7BQDKARQAyAS2AR8mdpE7wmwJoibdJUABQsA5vl6FRnLQEpUAPigAFQuwC2o1QB44Sc2SgB6d1F7FkTKNTUjCrcUABCKhAw7LQMGNRQ3orAonRQWhB8WApKkepG+PlmltZ2js6I5ugJiQQAFtYA7lCcEM0AooTWhOoA5PBhLexZEABmBhBYvUY1lFRzQczcoQCCnKI2THEQAB4SnFihEarRsfFUibwKqemZ2DnKqkXVF7WswMSEnFAqIJxpRRQ5iEYgkADoZBA5A88r1sopHhAwThprNqAsqL9-lBRsR-ikuFBNgZnjUODwssg0ExGkxxFA1hstsiYU8TJ4oAADHCcqD2KDsUYEcBqTkVTno6hAA)

---

If different subclasses would return different databases with different interfaces, then you can instead let the subclasses define that return type:

```
class BaseModel {
  static get database(): () => Promise<unknown> { // unknown here
    throw new Error('DB not defined')
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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-vlQdW1CAA)

Comment: I was worried this would be a case, however that's in 3rd party module(I guess I wasn't clear enough about that) - is there some workaround how to define it more loosely on the Animal? Maybe some union with void? (I don't know if that's even possible, and I think it shouldn't be)

Comment: I'm thinking maybe add a "tunel" layer between with the proper typing and extend that?

Comment: Offtopic: could you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71377277/property-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-static-parent-method please? only if you can... I've feeling you may know answer to that one too.