# Property * does not exist on type typeof * - static parent method

Tags: typescript, react-native, class, visual-studio-code, typescript-class

React Native, TypeScript code JS(non-TS) ORM module:

Parent `BaseModel`:

```
export default class BaseModel {
  static createTable() {
    ...
  }
  ...
```

My model of `Animal` does NOT redefine the method, it's just defined as:

`export default class Animal extends BaseModel { ...`

**Now this code `await Animal.createTable();` actually works**, but VSCode TypeScript checker gives following error in code:

```
Property 'createTable' does not exist on type 'typeof Animal'.ts(2339)
```

Is this the editor/checker issue? Or should the JS/TS code be defined somehow better?

Comment: Can you recreate this problem typescript playground? Because as far as I can tell, it works fine: https://tsplay.dev/WP7AJm

Comment: @AlexWayne as I said, the code works fine, I'm thinking maybe I tagged this wrong and it should be more of a VSCode issue, since it's just a code checker error, not a runtime error

Comment: The typescript playground, which I linked, will report any type errors. For instance: https://tsplay.dev/wX7JJW. So if you can recreate the _type_ error there then maybe we can help you. To to create a [minimal and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in that playground and paste a link to it in your question

Comment: Maybe this is related https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13206 , I believe there is not actual type error in typescript, since the code is working as expected, also still present in latest (1.65) I also tried adding `@augments` and `@extends` before child class, didn't help
Or maybe more this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863

Comment: btw, I'm bypassing dynamic methods by defining instances as `any` but if I don't there's same issue as with static methods

Answer (score 0):

So it seems to be a problem in vscode typescript intelisense not properly analyzing pure JS module (not typescript). Because if I create middl
e layer base model in typescript in project it recognizes it just fine. You have to redefine and proxy all used methods to the package parent, but it's still much less painful than adding them to each model.

Optionally, any `ts` error can be ignored by putting `// @ts-ignore` BEFORE the line, which I **don't recommend** if you can avoid it since potentially it could hide important errors.

```
// @ts-ignore
someLineWithTSerror;
```

My solution:

`AppBaseModel.tsx`

```
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite'
import { BaseModel } from 'expo-sqlite-orm'

export default class AppBaseModel extends BaseModel {
    constructor(obj) {
        super(obj)
    }

    static get database(): any {
        return async () => SQLite.openDatabase('MyAppDemoDB.db')
    }

    static createTable(): Promise<any> {
        return super.createTable();
    }

    static query(options): Promise<any> {
        return super.query(options);
    }

    save(): Promise<any> {
        return super.save();
    }
    // ...

}
```

`Animal.tsx`

```
import { types } from 'expo-sqlite-orm'

import AppBaseModel from 'pathToAppBaseModel/AppBaseModel'

export default class Animal extends AppBaseModel {
    constructor(obj) {
        super(obj)
    }

    static get tableName() {
        return 'animals'
    }

    static get columnMapping() {
        return {
            id: { type: types.INTEGER, primary_key: true }, // For while only supports id as primary key
            name: { type: types.TEXT, not_null: true },
            color: { type: types.TEXT },
            age: { type: types.NUMERIC },
            another_uid: { type: types.INTEGER, unique: true },
            timestamp: { type: types.INTEGER, default: () => Date.now() }
        }
    }
}
```

Example test usage

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import Animal from 'pathToAnimal/Animal'

// ... const SomeComponent = ({navigation}) => { ...

useEffect(() => {

    const testDB = async () => {
        await Animal.createTable();

        const props = {
            name: 'Bob',
            color: 'Brown',
            age: 2
        };

        const animal: Animal = new Animal(props);
        const save_result = await animal.save();
        let X_TEST = await Animal.query({
            columns: 'id, name',
            page: 1,
            limit: 30,
        });
        //X_TEST = [animal, save_result];
        Alert.alert ("X", JSON.stringify(X_TEST, null, 2));
    };
    testDB().catch(console.error);

});
```